# PDAL crashes when trying to filter noise points from outliers filter

Tags: lidar, filter, pdal, laz, outlier

I have a relatively simple PDAL pipeline being used to process a bunch of .laz files.

```
        {
            "type": "readers.las",
            "filename": "c:\\stuff\\10781001.laz"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.assign",
            "assignment": "Classification[:]=0"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.elm"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.outlier"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.smrf",
            "ignore": "Classification[7:7]",
            "slope": 0.2,
            "window": 16,
            "threshold": 0.45,
            "scalar": 1.2
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.hag"
        },
        ... more stages
```

It had been chugging along just fine - but eventually crashed. I tracked the error down to the smrf filter - specifically the ignore parameter. In this case, the ignore of classification values of 7 are the noise points identified in the previous pipeline stage (outlier filter). If I remove the ignore parameter from the stage - no errors.

So then I tried to just remove the noise points prior to smrf - but after the outliers stage. This too crashes PDAL:

```
{
            "type": "filters.range",
            "limits": "Classification![7:7]"
}
```

So I've saved the laz after the outlier stage. The text below is from lasinfo.  Any spot any major issues with this file that may be causing PDAL to crash?

```
lasinfo (190812) report for 'c:\stuff\10781001.laz'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            0
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          'PDAL'
  generating software:        'PDAL 1.9.1 (Releas)'
  file creation day/year:     300/2019
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       513
  number var. length records: 3
  point data format:          3
  point data record length:   34
  number of point records:    2007
  number of points by return: 1646 311 40 7 3
  scale factor x y z:         0.01 0.01 0.01
  offset x y z:               0 0 0
  min x y z:                  248117.29 3367475.09 61.34
  max x y z:                  248126.86 3367484.89 87.65
WARNING: stored resolution of min_x not compatible with x_offset and x_scale_factor: 248117.29483477573
WARNING: stored resolution of min_y not compatible with y_offset and y_scale_factor: 3367475.0859982171
WARNING: stored resolution of min_z not compatible with z_offset and z_scale_factor: 61.341999999999999
WARNING: stored resolution of max_x not compatible with x_offset and x_scale_factor: 248126.86283477573
WARNING: stored resolution of max_y not compatible with y_offset and y_scale_factor: 3367484.8929982171
WARNING: stored resolution of max_z not compatible with z_offset and z_scale_factor: 87.652999999999992
variable length header record 1 of 3:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  72
  description          'GeoTiff GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 8
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsArea
      key 1026 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 21 value_offset 0 - GTCitationGeoKey: NAD83 / UTM zone 15N
      key 2049 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 6 value_offset 21 - GeogCitationGeoKey: NAD83
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 2062 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 3 value_offset 0 - GeogTOWGS84GeoKey: TOWGS84[0,0,0]
      key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 26915 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: NAD83 / UTM 15N
      key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
variable length header record 2 of 3:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34736
  length after header  24
  description          'GeoTiff GeoDoubleParamsTag'
    GeoDoubleParamsTag (number of doubles 3)
      0 0 0 
variable length header record 3 of 3:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34737
  length after header  28
  description          'GeoTiff GeoAsciiParamsTag'
    GeoAsciiParamsTag (number of characters 28)
      NAD83 / UTM zone 15N|NAD83| 
LASzip compression (version 3.4r0 c2 50000): POINT10 2 GPSTIME11 2 RGB12 2
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X            24811729   24812686
  Y           336747509  336748489
  Z                6134       8765
  intensity           2      35409
  return_number       1          5
  number_of_returns   1          5
  edge_of_flight_line 0          0
  scan_direction_flag 0          0
  classification      0          7
  scan_angle_rank     0          0
  user_data           0          0
  point_source_ID     1          2
  gps_time 79997.732018 80500.322163
  Color R 5355 64770
        G 20910 64770
        B 17595 64770
WARNING: 1 points outside of header bounding box
number of first returns:        1646
number of intermediate returns: 40
number of last returns:         1730
number of single returns:       1409
overview over number of returns of given pulse: 1409 499 74 18 7 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
            1928  never classified (0)
              79  noise (7)
WARNING: real min x smaller than header min x by 0.004835
```

Comment: Can you post the file that crashes somewhere I can get it to test?

Comment: Hi Howard.  Here is link:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SOw1ZbKAxk2DSzJYVFfrJ--rzVcpCBDZ  One quick note... The .laz file as delivered to me has no CRS defined.  It is in UTM Zone 15N EPSG 26915.  In the first stage of my pipeline - I do have it specified there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is strange.

First, an EPSG code of 0 isn't valid.

```
LOCAL_CS["unnamed",AUTHORITY["EPSG","0"]]
```

Second, SMRF is designed for aerial LiDAR data, not this (bridge superstructure?).

[image: point file]

Third, there's a bug in the SMRF knn code that is triggered by this particular point configuration. Please follow https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/2794 for details.